# How to create a salesforce report as shown in the screenshot attached?

Tags: reporting

I need to create a report in the format which is shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Sample Report Format]

In the report, Total No of Notes, Total No of Attachments,Agent Name, Date are all coming from the same object called agent information.

I tried creating a matrix report but i couldn't get it to look like the one which i need.

[image: Matrix Report Format]

Answer (score 0):

You can build this kind of report via Matrix report. In the matrix report, you can group the data by Date at one end and Agent name at the other end. On the group by date, the default is individual date. You can convert that to group by Calendar Week, Calendar Month, Calendar quarter, calendar year, fiscal year, etc. Once this grouping is done, you can then summarize the total no of notes and total no of attachments. You will also need to do hide details.

See below for more info:
[Creating a matrix report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_reports_matrix.htm)

Comment: I have attached the matrix report which i created. I could not get it to look like the one i need.

Comment: If you want the values side-by-side instead of one-on-top-of-another, you're out of luck. SFDC does not allow that.

Comment: @Sebastian Kessel Oh! Ok Fine. Is there any possibility to rename the "Sum of TotalCountofInvestorsContacted" to "Total Count of Investors Contacted".

Comment: @Ean Sebastian is right; SFDC does not allow that. Also, I don't think if renaming is possible.